# XLConnect How To Change NA Values in R

Tags: r, xlconnect

I am working with R and XLConnect package.  I have a test.xlsx file that contains the following values in excel:

Excel Data

```
Region  Dist    Sales
1        11      10
2        11
```

I run this the below code:

```
require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx",create=FALSE)
data1 <- readWorksheet ( wb , "sheet1" , header=TRUE)

data1
Output
Region  Dist    Sales
1         11    10
2         11    NA
```

How do I force the NA to 0 preferably using XLconnect if possible?

Comment: `data1[sapply(data1,is.na)] = 0`

Comment: +1 @Vlo `data1[is.na(data1)] <- 0` no need to use `sapply`. Put it as an answer.